# Null pointer a pesar de controlarlo

Tags: java

He hecho una web y utilizo una función ajax pasando el producto y en otra no.
Cuando llega al servlet lo controlo.

```
    if(!request.getParameter("producto").equals("") &&  request.getParameter("producto") !=null &&    !request.getParameter("producto").equals(null)) {
        cadena = "---VACIO---";
    }else {
        cadena = "---NO ESTA VACIO---";
    }
```

Y a pesar de tenerlo controlado me devuelve un null Pointer. ¿Sabeis porque puede ser? Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: esto pasa por tu primer condición ya que estas comparando un nulo contra una cadena vacia lo cual te regresa excepción, para confirmar esto puedes separar tus condiciones en 3 distintos if y ves en cada uno si pasa o no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**La primera validación (de izquierda a derecha) debe ser precisamente la que evalúa null**, por lo tanto lo correcto sería:

```
 if(request != null && request.getParameter("producto") !=null && !request.getParameter("producto").equals("") &&    !request.getParameter("producto").equals(null)) {
        cadena = "---VACIO---";
    }else {
        cadena = "---NO ESTA VACIO---";
    }
```

Comment: perfecto me funcionó gracias